# Swift Extension Bad Access

Tags: ios, swift

I have a simple extension on UIView to return all the frame values shorthand.

```
extension UIView {
    var x: CGFloat { return self.frame.origin.x }
    var y: CGFloat { return self.frame.origin.y }
    var width: CGFloat { return self.frame.size.width }
    var height: CGFloat { return self.frame.size.height }
}
```

However whenever I access `self.view.width` from a view controller, my app crashes with a bad access message. I've tried a few different variations on the extension including `{ return CGRectGetMinX(self.frame)` and

```
let f = self.frame
return f.size.width
```

but the error persists throughout all cases.

Comment: Looks like a bug. This works for me with the newest Beta 6.

Comment: Hmmm strange, that's what I'm on.